# Something like mb_glob in PHP ZendServer for IBM i

Tags: php, character-encoding, ibm-midrange, glob

In an IBM i (the system formerly known as AS/400) I have a folder with this elements:

```
Àlex Corretgé          DIR  
carpeta sense codi >   DIR  
test.txt               STMF 
Barça                  DIR  
Còpia de test.txt      STMF
```

When I run the [`glob` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with `*.*` pattern i.e. I get

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(89) "[...]/lex Corretg"
  [1]=>
  string(81) "[...]/Bara"
  [2]=>
  string(95) "[...]/carpeta sense codis"
  [3]=>
  string(93) "[...]/Cpia de test.txt"
  [4]=>
  string(84) "[...]/test.txt"
}
```

note: [...] is for clearly pourpose.

I read the PHP glob manual, but there isn't any reference for charset issues.

I look for a mb_glob function or similar. Already exists?

I'm at last PTF level

```
SF99115-20  IBM HTTP SERVER FOR I
```

And PHP Version 5.3.6 extension 20090626

scandir() function runs with the same issue

But if I do:

```
        $handle = opendir($globPath);
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            echo  utf8_encode($file) . "\n";
        }
```

the results are the expected! Yes, I can write my own mb_glob to prevent the multibyte issue, but anybody know if there is an official alternative?

Comment: Looks like that PHP is using the systems implementation of the glob command: http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/dir.c#423 - maybe you can solve this if you can solve it on the OS level.

Comment: It works here (proper names returned in call), so I indeed suspect its a setting at the OS level somewhere... Maybe not unimportant: what character set _are_ the filenames in?

Comment: yes @hakre , is the system implementation, I can't use GLOB_BRACE i.e.

Comment: @Wrikken the files with non-Ascii chars in the name created by the application, are in charid 819 and I gets well. But the files uploaded from Windows with share folders are in charid 1252 and I gets wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If I start the shell console with STRQSH and execute ls, I get wrong results even with files created from the console (i.e. echo Hello > MésIMés.txt ) created with charid 284. utf8_encode(readdir($dh)) returns results as expected.